# Should we create base test class which contains additionals mocks?

Tags: unit-testing

When we have a classes like

```
class IntoController(IViewModelCreator viewModelCreator) {}
```

and

```
class ProductController(ICommandFactory commandFactory, IViewModelCreator viewModelCreator) {}
```

and

```
class ProductController(ICommandFactory commandFactory, IViewModelCreator viewModelCreator, IRepository repository) {}
```

and a lot of more. It takes a lot of time to mock this interfaces each time. What do you think about general purpose class which contains a big set of mocks?

```
class BaseControllerUnitTests
{
    protected Mock<IViewModelCreator> ViewModelCreator { get;set; }
    protected Mock<ICommandFactory> ViewModelCreator { get;set; }
    protected Mock<IRepository> ViewModelCreator { get;set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually do this; I just keep them in a different class called `TestDataFactory` so I don't get into problems with inheritance (just in case I have to extend some other base class in a test).

The factory shouldn't be global/static (see below).

Pro:

- There is a single place for all tests to go to get a valid object graph
- If the object graph changes, there is just one place to go to fix all the tests
- You can keep references to the mocks in the factory for mocking inner method calls (i.e. you can ask for a `ProductController` and later, when you ask for an `ICommandFactory`, you get the one which was injected into the controller).

Con:

- The test factory will become quite big. Eventually, you'll have to split it into several files.
- Not all tests need the exact same mockup. Sometimes, you'll need to insert a real object. My solution is to allow to override the references which the factory keeps. But it makes the code even more clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Aaron Digulla's answer I'd like to suggest my [colleague's post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-unit-testing) with some examples. He calls it Test Context. I use this approach pretty much as well.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that's you're writing test code shouldn't mean that all software engineering best practices should go out the window.
If you have a subset of common functionality between your tests (in this case - mocking some methods of the tested class) then yes, by all means - you can extract a base class.